# Drawing LOTS of MKPolylines efficiently. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I've an app whose function is to run in the background, collecting location data ('runkeeper' style app). It could potentially be running for hours, and collect thousands of points.

These 'runs' are listed in a tableview and on selection it will redraw that run on the map. I'm also coloring these polylines, so in order to have multiple colors on a seemingly single line, I connect a bunch of different polylines. When I go to add an NSArray containing (say 700) lines, and use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ 
            lineArray = [self polylinesFromSession]; 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [map addOverlays:lineArray] // lineArray.count = ~700
            });
});
```

It really, really, bogs the app down for a 10-15 seconds. I can't use addOverlays on any thread other than main, so I don't see many options here. Is it possible to join a bunch of lines into a single overlay, THEN add it to the map? Or, any ideas for a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your data points are contiguous, instead of adding hundreds of different lines, try to combine them into a single line with many points.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating raster tiles (with alpha transparency) of your lines on the fly and adding those as an `MKTileOverlay` to your map. For each point in a line, you can figure out in "tile space" what point this corresponds to, and use Core Graphics to draw in that tile. You can also skip points that would be over or under previous lines' points (unless you are plotting in a different color or want to layer the lines in a specific way).

The math is a little of the scope of an answer here, but Spherical Mercator is relatively easy to grasp as the world is a large square continuously tiled into smaller squares and the projection math is relatively straightforward trigonometry.

But you will likely find higher performance out of rasterizing this way, as long as you don't need to interact with the various line annotations individually in the app, but just show them.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer?  I am trying to draw CGPaths in my MKTileOverlay, but if the map is panning or zooming the lines do not appear- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066894/drawing-cgpath-in-mktileoverlayrenderer